# What Is better? Two Hashmaps or One making use of a Class?

Tags: java

I'm currently programming something where I'm paying a lot of attention to performance and ram usage.

I came wondering with this problem, and I was trying to make a decision. Imagine this situation:

I need to associate a certain Class (Location) and a Integer to a String (let's say a name). So a Name has an Id and a Location....

What would be the best approach to this?

First: Create two hashmaps

```
HashMap<String, Location> one = new HashMap<String, Location>
HashMap<String, Integer> two = new HashMap<String, Integer>
```

Second: Use only one hashmap and create a new class

```
HashMap<String, NewClass> one = new HashMap<String, NewClass>
```

where NewClass contains:

```
class NewClass {

    Location loc;
    Integer int;
}
```

Comment: This question will elicit much opinion rather than a single, helpful answer. Perhaps run some some tests to evaluate access times, construction etc and then return with a more concise question.

Comment: If I was to run some tests, I would already have an answer. Instead of arguments to create a new question... But thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always need to retrieve both Id and Location, the first approach would require 2 Hash lookups while the second approach would require only 1. In that case, the second approach should have a slight better performance.

To test that I did the simple test below:

```
// create 2 hashes with 1M entries
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    String s = new BigInteger(80, random).toString(32);
    hash1.put(s, s);
    hash2.put(s, new BigInteger(80, random).intValue());
}

// create 1 hash with 1M entries
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    String s = new BigInteger(80, random).toString(32);
    NewClass n = new NewClass();
    n.i = new BigInteger(80, random).intValue();
    n.loc = s;
    hash3.put(s, n);
}

// 5M lookups
long start = new Date().getTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++){
    String s = "AAA";
    hash1.get(s);
    hash2.get(s);
}
System.out.println("Approach 1 (2 hashes): " + (new Date().getTime() - start));

// 5M lookups
long start2 = new Date().getTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++){
    String s = "BBB";
    hash3.get(s);
}
System.out.println("Approach 2 (1 hash): " + (new Date().getTime() - start2));
```

Running on my computer, the results were:

- Approach 1 (2 hashes): 37 ms
- Approach 2 (1 hash): 18 ms

The test is super simplistic and, if you are to consider serious performance issues, you should investigate deeper into this issue, considering other aspects as memory footprint, cost of object creation, etc. But, in any case, using 2 hashes will increase the total lookup time.

Comment: Right, second approach should have a better performance. I edited the answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want every String to be coupled with BOTH the location and integer, use a new class, it will be much easier to debug and maintain, because it makes sense. A String X is connected to both a location and an integer. It ensures you will do less mistakes (like inserting only one of them, or deleting only one), and will be more readable.

If the association is loose, and some strings might need only location, and some only integers - using two maps is probably preferable, as future readers of the code (including you in 3 months) will fail to understand what is this new class and why the String X needs to have a location.

tl;dr:

- `String->MyClass` if each string is always associated with a location and an integer
- `String->Integer, String->Location` if each string is independently assiciated with locations and integers.